# Moving a project from one Azure DevOps to another

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm a member of one of my colleague's personal Azure DevOps Services organization (I hope I'm using that term correctly). And there's another Azure DevOps organization that we're both a part of. In my colleague's personal organization there's a project I've been working on for a while. My colleague and I both agree that it would be best, at this time, to move that project from his personal organization to our company's organization in Azure DevOps Services. Only, we don't know how to do that.

So, is it possible to move a project (code, wiki, board, etc.) from one Azure DevOps organization to another? If so, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: No, it's not possible to move a project between organizations. The best you can do is employ various migration tools to recreate the work item data in the new organization, and accept that there is going to be some degree of loss of fidelity. For example, you can easily move your repos, but pull requests are simply not transferrable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel Mann's answered my question in his comment in reply to my question:

> No, it's not possible to move a project between organizations. The
> best you can do is employ various migration tools to recreate the work
> item data in the new organization, and accept that there is going to
> be some degree of loss of fidelity. For example, you can easily move
> your repos, but pull requests are simply not transferrable.